# Would the joint distribution of Normal Random Variable and the distribution of a X bar from the same sample be bivariate Normal?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I know this question is somewhat redundant... but here goes:

My text asserts that the joint distribution of $$X_1=N(\theta, 1)\text{ and } \bar X = N(\theta, \frac 1n)$$ 
is Bivariate normal with $$\text{mean vector} = (\theta, \theta), \, \sigma_1^2 = 1,\ \sigma_2^2 = \frac 1n,\text{ and } \rho = 1/\sqrt n$$

Given the numerous reasons to not assume a Bivariate normal joint distribution  as a result of two marginal normals, many summed up nicely here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d/30205#30205,

why is it okay (to make assumptions) in this case? Also, how could the covariance be computed in this situation? The text offers a problem to show this result later in problems, thus prompting this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nobody is *making assumptions* in this matter; rather, someone is *drawing conclusions*. And those conclusions are *not* based simply on the marginal distributions.  Conventionally, one has
$$
X_1,\ldots,X_n \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}\sim N(\theta,1),
$$
$$
\bar X = \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \sim N\left(\theta,\frac 1 n \right)
$$
This gives use the mean vector and the two variances.  Then we have
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{cov}\left( X_1, \bar X \right) = \operatorname{cov}\left( X_1, \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right) \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac 1 n \Big( \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_1)+\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) + \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_3)+\cdots +\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_n) \Big) \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac 1 n \Big( 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 \Big) = \frac 1 n.
\end{align}

Finally, we have the question of why this has a bivariate normal distribution. The definition of the statement that $(U,V)$ has a bivariate normal distribution is that for every pair of constants $a$, $b$ (and "constant" means not random) the random variable $aU+bV$ has a univariate normal distribution.  So we need the distribution of $aX_1+b\bar X$.  Observe that
$$
aX_1+b\bar X = aX_1+b\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n} n = \underbrace{\left(a+\frac b n\right)X_1 + b\frac{X_2}n+\cdots+b\frac{X_n}n}.
$$
Notice that the part over the underbrace is a sum of **independent** random variables each of which is normally distributed.  Consequently it is itself normally distributed.  This conclusion is not based merely on the marginal distributions because it relies on independence.

Comment: +1, nicely put (including the necessary debunking of misconceptions).

Comment: Awesome explanation! Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Redeyes10 : Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for this follow question. But may I just conclude that the distribution of $(X_1,\ldots, X_n, \bar X)$ will have the mutinomal distribution? If so, what is the expression? Let's just take $n=2$ for simplicity